# How to set ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> in AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

How to set ArrayList with HashMap in AlertDialog?

```
// Creating and Building the Dialog 
AlertDialog dialogBox = null;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Select Item:");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
           switch(item){
                 case 0:
                      // Your code when first option selected
                      break;        
           }
           dialogBox.dismiss();    
        }
});
dialogBox = builder.create();
dialogBox.show();
```

I hope somebody to help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can we have more details plz ?

Comment: I have ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items;
And I want to set up at builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...

Comment: first convert you hash map to String Array List then convert Arrat List Array and pass this simple Array to Alert Dialog.

Comment: I have tried with String[] = new String[] items = new String[]{"bla", "bla", "bla"};
It's working. I want to convert  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items; to String[] items;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listMap =  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String,String> map1 =new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("title","Amdroid1");
HashMap<String,String> map2 =new HashMap<String, String>();
map2.put("title","Amdroid2");
HashMap<String,String> map3 =new HashMap<String, String>();
map3.put("title","Amdroid3");
HashMap<String,String> map4 =new HashMap<String, String>();
map4.put("title","Amdroid4");
HashMap<String,String> map5 =new HashMap<String, String>();
map5.put("title","Amdroid5");

listMap.add(map1);
listMap.add(map2);
listMap.add(map3);
listMap.add(map4);
listMap.add(map5);

ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
for(HashMap<String,String> row : listMap){
    listString.add(row.get("title"));
}

String[] array = listString.toArray(new String[listString.size()]);
System.out.print("Lenght "+array.length);
```

Comment: what if i have 2 attributes for each map? 
e.g 
map1.put("title","Amdroid1");
map1.put("id","unique number");

and in my alertdialog, when i choose first title, i get the id number.